# ExceptionInInitializerError in JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I am trying to use JavaCV, but I am getting ExceptionInInitializerError .

Here are the logs:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:553)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:156)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber.grab(VideoInputFrameGrabber.java:163)
    at com.sudev.robo.Robot.run(Robot.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:456)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:581)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:134)
    ... 8 more
```

Can somebody help me with the issue. I am using JavaCV 0.6 , OpenCV 2.4.7 and Microsoft visual c++ 2010 redistributable x64

The code of the program is here :

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvFlip;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class Robot implements Runnable {
    IplImage image;
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");

    public Robot() {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0);
        // 1 for next camera
        int i = 0;
        try {
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img = null;
            while (true) {
                 long sleepTime= (long)((1000 / 60));
                    img = grabber.grab();
                if (img != null) {
                    cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
                    cvSaveImage((i++) + "-aa.jpg", img); // show image on window
                    canvas.showImage(img);
                } 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot gs = new Robot();
        Thread th = new Thread(gs);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which class's initializer is throwing the error? We'll need to see its code.

Comment: Hi Chrylis, I have added the code as well

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the class we need. The exception is getting thrown inside a class that is getting loaded reflectively by the class initializer (not constructor) for `opencv_core$CvArr`, and we need to see what class that is. I'm not familiar with OpenCV, so I don't know whether it's loading one of your classes from a configuration file somewhere or one of its own internal ones. Set your debugger to break on `ExceptionInInitializerError` and look at the argument for `Class.forName()`.

Comment: Its a part of JavaCV jars, it is not a class that I have made. I have created only one class and I have shared that with you

Comment: Nothing else we can do until you find out the class name that's being passed to `forName()`.

Comment: What JVM are you using?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I am using JVM 1.7

Answer (score 0):

For those who found this error whilst using JavaCV and trying to load the camera...

I found importing all the files from the below file solved my problem.

https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-0.6-cppjars.zip